# How can I get the position of a moving SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKSpriteNode that moves back and forth.
I need to get it's position as it moves (so it changes all the time) and get different positions as it moves across the screen.

When I try and receive the position it comes as the original position.

Object movement:

```
let right = SKAction.moveBy(x: self.frame.width, y: 0, duration: 3)
let left = SKAction.moveBy(x: -self.frame.width, y: 0, duration: 3)
```

And this is what I'm trying to do to get it's position printed as it goes.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    pos = String(describing: blockposition.x)
    print(pos)
}
```

Is it possible to get one that updates as it moves?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code example at least! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've had trouble accessing the properties of sprites being moved by actions - what are you trying to do? There might be another way.

Answer (score 1):

in your "class"

1_ type var sprite(the name of your sprite) = SKSpriteNode()

2_ then add your synod to the scene

3_ then in the update func call print(sprite(the name of your sprite).position.x or y) as you want hope it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction?changes=_1

**Observing Changes to Node Properties**
Generally, actions do not call public methods on nodes. For example, if you wanted to subclass SKNode to respond to a move(to:duration:) action, you may consider overriding its position property to add a didSet observer (see Overriding Property Observers).

```
class MovingNode: SKSpriteNode {
    override var position: CGPoint {
        didSet {
            // code to react to position change
        }
    }
}
```

However, because a move action running on an instance of MovingNode doesn't set its position, the observer isn't invoked and your code to react to a position change is never executed.

In this example, the solution is to use SKSceneDelegate. By comparing a node's position in the delegate's update(_:for:) method - which is called at the beginning of each frame - to its position in the delegate's didEvaluateActions(for:) method - which is called after any actions have been evaluated - you can check if it has moved and react accordingly.

Listing 7 shows an example of how you can implement this solution.

Listing 7 
Responding to a position change during a running action

```
let node = SKNode()
var nodePosition = CGPoint()

func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval, for scene: SKScene) {
    nodePosition = node.position
}

func didEvaluateActions(for scene: SKScene) {
    let distance = hypot(node.position.x - nodePosition.x,
                         node.position.y - nodePosition.y)

    if distance > 0 {
        // code to react to position change
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are going to assign the node position every frame, you may as well just assign it to itself to allow the didSet to fire,  then you do not need to mess with distance formula

Comment: Don’t ask me - I’m just posting how Apple say to do it 

Comment: yeah....Apple sucks lol.  I just realized this doesn't answer his question.  If he applied your code,  the `nodePosition` is still going to yield the same numbers.  There is something in his question he is not telling us.

Comment: It still gives the same position. I have the object going back and forth and I want to be able to get it's exact position at any given time, so I'm starting to try and get it at all positions.

Comment: I'm guilty here of not testing this code - I'm sure that accessing a node's properties which are being changed via an action is tricky, though...